# CefSharp Change UserAgent in real time

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I'm using `CefSharp` in My `Winform` Project and i want to change the User-Agent for specific browser only.

I do it by using custom `IRequestHandler` and setting there the user agent with :

```
class IGRequestHandler : IRequestHandler
{
    public bool CanGetCookies(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool CanSetCookie(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, Cookie cookie)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public bool GetAuthCredentials(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, bool isProxy, string host, int port, string realm, string scheme, IAuthCallback callback)
    {
        callback.Dispose();
        return false;
    }

    public IResponseFilter GetResourceResponseFilter(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public bool OnBeforeBrowse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool userGesture, bool isRedirect)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        var headers = request.Headers;
        headers["User-Agent"] = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1";
        request.Headers = headers;
        return CefReturnValue.Continue;
    }

    public bool OnCertificateError(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefErrorCode errorCode, string requestUrl, ISslInfo sslInfo, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        callback.Dispose();
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnOpenUrlFromTab(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnPluginCrashed(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string pluginPath)
    {

    }

    public bool OnProtocolExecution(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string url)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnQuotaRequest(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, string originUrl, long newSize, IRequestCallback callback)
    {
        callback.Dispose();
        return false;
    }

    public void OnRenderProcessTerminated(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, CefTerminationStatus status)
    {

    }

    public void OnRenderViewReady(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser)
    {

    }

    public void OnResourceLoadComplete(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, UrlRequestStatus status, long receivedContentLength)
    {

    }

    public void OnResourceRedirect(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response, ref string newUrl)
    {

    }

    public bool OnResourceResponse(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IResponse response)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public bool OnSelectClientCertificate(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, bool isProxy, string host, int port, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection certificates, ISelectClientCertificateCallback callback)
    {
        callback.Dispose();
        return false;
    }
}
```

When i load the page with this i still get the regular version of the website and not the mobile version.

when i change the useragent with:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();

settings.CachePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData) + @"\CEF";
settings.IgnoreCertificateErrors = true;
settings.WindowlessRenderingEnabled = true;
settings.SetOffScreenRenderingBestPerformanceArgs();
settings.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_0_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/602.1.50 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/10.0 Mobile/14A403 Safari/602.1";

Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: false, browserProcessHandler: null);
```

I'm getting the mobile version but i want to do it in real time and not for every browser.

This is how i'm implement the browser:

```
instaBrowser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("");
instaBrowser.RequestHandler = new IGRequestHandler();

instaBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
instaBrowser.FrameLoadEnd += webViewFrameLoadEnd;
instaBrowser.LoadError += getFromBrowser_LoadError;

instaBrowser.BrowserSettings.Plugins = CefState.Disabled;
instaBrowser.BrowserSettings.WebGl = CefState.Disabled;
instaBrowser.BrowserSettings.RemoteFonts = CefState.Disabled;
instaBrowser.BrowserSettings.WindowlessFrameRate = 1;

instaBrowser.JsDialogHandler = new JsDialogHandler();

instaPanel.Controls.Add(instaBrowser);
```

Comment: Topic has been covered many times before,  see https://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=14578

Answer (score 3):

This was difficult to find, but it seems like:

```
browser.GetDevToolsClient().Emulation.SetUserAgentOverrideAsync("");
```

Changes the useragent succesfully even when the browser object is already created.

For example I have this method, which is handling the "OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged" event:

```
    private void OnIsBrowserInitializedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (DevToolsClient DTC = browser.GetDevToolsClient()) {
            DTC.Emulation.SetUserAgentOverrideAsync("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; en-us; SCH-I535 Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30");
        }
    }
```

And when I do:

```
browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent");
```

The site shows me the exact same string as I entered.

Comment: GetDevToolsClient returns a http://cefsharp.github.io/api/85.3.x/html/T_CefSharp_DevTools_DevToolsClient.htm instance which implements IDisposable and as such should be wrapped in a using block or dispose called manually.

Comment: You will nedd to be using version 85 or above to use this.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've quickly added a link to this answer in https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#useragent